# php login script not working and , it doesnt redirect back to the dashboard

Tags: php, session, redirect

i have not been able to get this, i have been on this for days ,i dont know if its from the login page or the dashboard , but my login script doesnt redirect to the dashboard

i have tried alot of things and even added an echo at every line of code , it shows that , the scripts get to the redirect and actually redirects but still comes back to the login page

```
<?php require 'sqlconnect.php' ?>

<?php
    session_start(); 
?>
<?php

    $email= '';
    $password = '';

    $errors = '';
    $success = '';

    if(isset($_REQUEST['login'])){

        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

        if(empty($email)){
            $errors .= '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        Email field is empty.
                    </div>';
            }
        if(empty($password)){
            $errors .= '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        Password field is empty.
                    </div>';
        }
        if(!empty($email) and !empty($password)){

            $confirm_info = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'");

            if(mysqli_num_rows($confirm_info) >= 1){
                echo "if statement";

                while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($confirm_info)) {
                    $token = $results['token'];
                    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
                    header("Location: dashboard/profile.php");
                }
            }else{
                $errors .= '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            Login credentials doesn\'nt exist is our database.
                        </div>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
</head>
<body>


        <form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST" action="login.php">
            <span class="login100-form-title p-b-37">
                Sign In
                <!-- <i class="fa fa-home uk-align-center uk-text-center"></i> -->
            </span>
            <?php
                echo $errors;
                //echo $success;
            ?>
            <br>

            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-20" data-validate="Enter username or email">
                <input class="input100" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-25" data-validate = "Enter password">
                <input class="input100" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                <button class="login100-form-btn" id="login" name="login">
                    Sign In
                    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" id="spinner" style="display: none"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center p-t-57 p-b-20">
                <span class="txt1">
                <a href="forgetpassword.php" class="txt2 hov1">
                    forget password
                    <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-5"></i>
                </a>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center p-t-57 p-b-20">
                <span class="txt1">
                    Or Create  an account
                </span>
            </div>


            <!-- <div class="flex-c p-b-112">
                <a href="#" class="login100-social-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="login100-social-item">
                    <img src="login/images/icons/icon-google.png" alt="GOOGLE">
                </a>
            </div> -->
<!-- 
            <div class="text-center">
                <a href="#" class="txt2 hov1">
                    Sign Up
                </a>
            </div> -->
        </form>
        <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
            <a href="signup.php" class="txt2 hov1 text-light">
                <button class="signin100-form-btn">
                   Sign Up
                </button>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the dashboard profile page code

```
<?php require '../sqlconnect.php' ?>
<?php 
  session_start();
  $token = $_SESSION['token'];
    if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){
        header("Location: ../login.php");
        exit();
    }else{

      $all_details = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE token = '$token'");

      if(mysqli_num_rows($all_details)){

        $results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all_details);
        $id = $results['id'];
        $token = $results['token'];
        $email = $results['email'];
        $first_name = $results['first_name'];
        $is_admin = $results['is_admin'];
        $last_name = $results['last_name'];
        $usernam = $results['username'];
        $image_name = $results['image_name'];
        $image_dir = $results['image_dir'];

        // echo $username;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ah, so the redirect might be working, but the dashboard profile page sends you right back to the login when `$_SESSION['token']` is not set. Since it is not set anywhere, I guess that that must be the reason behind your problems.

Comment: You're not setting the session in your login page. Set session `$_SESSION['token'] = $token` before `header("Location: dashboard/profile.php");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characters that are not in PHP quote `<?php ?>` are treated as HTML output. And if the PHP page send any HTML output to the browser, the header would be sent at the same time. That's why any `header()` call after closing tag `?>` would be useless.

You need to change your login page, or any page with `header()` calls to not close `?>` before calling. For example:

```php
<?php

require 'sqlconnect.php';
session_start(); 

    $email= '';
    $password = '';

    $errors = '';
    $success = '';

    if(isset($_REQUEST['login'])){

        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

        if(empty($email)){
            $errors .= '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        Email field is empty.
                    </div>';
            }
        if(empty($password)){
            $errors .= '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        Password field is empty.
                    </div>';
        }
        if(!empty($email) and !empty($password)){

            $confirm_info = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'");

            if(mysqli_num_rows($confirm_info) >= 1){
                echo "if statement";

                while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($confirm_info)) {
                    $token = $results['token'];
                    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
                    header("Location: dashboard/profile.php");
                }
            }else{
                $errors .= '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            Login credentials doesn\'nt exist is our database.
                        </div>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
</head>
<body>


        <form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST" action="login.php">
            <span class="login100-form-title p-b-37">
                Sign In
                <!-- <i class="fa fa-home uk-align-center uk-text-center"></i> -->
            </span>
            <?php
                echo $errors;
                //echo $success;
            ?>
            <br>

            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-20" data-validate="Enter username or email">
                <input class="input100" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-25" data-validate = "Enter password">
                <input class="input100" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                <button class="login100-form-btn" id="login" name="login">
                    Sign In
                    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" id="spinner" style="display: none"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center p-t-57 p-b-20">
                <span class="txt1">
                <a href="forgetpassword.php" class="txt2 hov1">
                    forget password
                    <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-5"></i>
                </a>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center p-t-57 p-b-20">
                <span class="txt1">
                    Or Create  an account
                </span>
            </div>


            <!-- <div class="flex-c p-b-112">
                <a href="#" class="login100-social-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="login100-social-item">
                    <img src="login/images/icons/icon-google.png" alt="GOOGLE">
                </a>
            </div> -->
<!-- 
            <div class="text-center">
                <a href="#" class="txt2 hov1">
                    Sign Up
                </a>
            </div> -->
        </form>
        <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
            <a href="signup.php" class="txt2 hov1 text-light">
                <button class="signin100-form-btn">
                   Sign Up
                </button>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You'd need similar changes in the profile page, but you should have got the idea from the above example.

Comment: this works like a charm , i did this and it worked , thankls alot

Answer (score 0):

I think you reversed your variable assignment here:

```
while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($confirm_info)) {
                    $token = $results['token'];
                    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
                    header("Location: dashboard/profile.php");
                }
```

This should be

```
while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($confirm_info)) {
                    $_SESSION['token'] = $results['token'];
                    header("Location: dashboard/profile.php");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In login page

```
while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($confirm_info))
{
    $token = $results['token'];
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    header("Location: dashboard/profile.php");
}
```

Comment: this did not work , it still redirects me back to the login page and i must say that it works well on localhost but not on live

Comment: this was one of my problems as well , thanks alot i guess after i applied the previous answer , this just complimented it, thanks alot